# Solr Heap Dump - How to diagnose

Tags: search, solr, lucene

Got a heap dump on an Out of Memory error.
Analyzing the dump now in Visual VM

Seeing a lot of byte[] arrays (77% of our 8GB Heap) in

`TreeMap$Entry
FieldCacheImpl$SortedDocValues`

We’re considering switch over to turn on docValues to 'true' for fields we sort on but would rather be definitive about the root cause before we experiment with DocValues and require a reindex of our 200M document index 
In each of our 4 data centers.

Any suggestions on what I should look for in this heap dump to get a definitive root cause?

Answer (score 1):

You are pretty much almost guaranteed things would improve by enabling docvalues. If you want some proof before doing the big reindexing, you could just:

1. create a smaller version of your current setup, say 20M
2. run it in a smaller jvm heap size, like 1GB. See it OOM, if it does not, decrease the heap until it OOMs
3. now enable docvalues, reindex and run on the same heap, it should be clearly better
4. now you can implement docvalues in your real prod setup with some peace of mind

Edit on your comment: well, if you are sorting on 200M docs...not sure if a heap of 4GB is so huge. You could check if you are caching fq that you don't need/are ineffective (like having NOW in a date field with millisecond accuracy). fqs will take some memory in large indexes.

Comment: Thanks yes we did add docValues and things improved remarkably saving about 2-3 GB of heap going from a peak of 7GB to a peak of 4GB. That said 4GB of heap still is pretty large and we'd like to know what else to look for in the heap dump - any caches or areas to focus on. Thanks!

Comment: added some comment

Comment: Thanks for the update - yes to be on the safe side we disabled the filterCache (< 1% of our queries use the fq and the hit rate on that cache is < 1%).